# 'ALL' concept in SQL queries

Tags: sql

Relational Schema:

```
Students (**sid**, name, age, major)

Courses (**cid**, name)

Enrollment (**sid**, **cid**, year, term, grade)
```

Write a SQL query that returns the name of the students who took all courses.I'm not sure how I capture the concept of 'ALL' in a SQL query.

EDIT:
I want to be able write it without aggregation as I want to use the same logic for writing the query in relational algebra as well.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: This appears to be an assignment. Whoever wrote it seems to be using the word “all“ in its plain English sense. I don’t think there is a technical concept of “all.“ There is a keyword `all` in SQL,  but it does not apply here.

Comment: Sure - my question is how to translate this requirement to a SQL query.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. [mcve]. Also show us your current query attempt,

Comment: Hint: `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of writing such queries is to count the number of course and number of courses each student took, and compare them:

```sql
SELECT s.*
FROM   students s
JOIN   (SELECT   sid, COUNT(DISTINCT cid) AS student_courses
        FROM     enrollment
        GROUP BY sid) e ON s.sid = e.sid
JOIN   (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM   courses) c ON cnt = student_cursed
```

Comment: Interesting - can we do it without aggregation ?

Comment: @tomer - why would you even want to?

Comment: Might want `COUNT(DISTINCT cid)` as the student appears to be able to take the same course multiple times in different years.

Comment: Because the next thing I want to do is  to write it in relational algebra that doe not have aggregation and I want to have the same logic applied to both cases.

Comment: @tomer Then specify the need for both in your question.

Comment: @MatBailie If I'm reading the question correctly, the combination `sid,cid` is a composite primary key in `enrollment`, so using `count(*)` and `count(distinct cid)` would have the same result when you group by `sid`. If I misunderstood and this isn't true, you are of course correct. In fact, even if this is correct, using `count(distinct cid)` is more intuitive to read - I'll update my answer accordingly. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

This gives course combinations that are possible but haven't been taken...

```
SELECT s.sid, c.cid FROM students CROSS JOIN courses
EXCEPT
SELECT sid, cid FROM enrollment
```

So, you can then do the same with the student list...

```
SELECT sid FROM students
EXCEPT
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        sid
    FROM
    (
        SELECT s.sid, c.cid FROM students CROSS JOIN courses
        EXCEPT
        SELECT sid, cid FROM enrollment
    )
        AS not_enrolled
)
    AS slacker_students
```

I don't like it, but it avoids aggregation...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Students
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Courses
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Enrollment ON Courses.cid = Enrollment.cid 
                              AND Enrollment.sid = Students.sid
    WHERE Enrollment.sid IS NULL
)
```

btw. names of tables should be in singular form, not plural